SPI Communication with IMU LSM6DSOX using STM32H562RGV6
Iam using STM32H562RGV6 for my project and iam using SPI6 on this MCU in order to communicate with LSM6DSOX which is an IMU from ST itself but i couldn’t get proper data from the IMU, as its giving random data sometimes and sometimes its zero.
Pin connections :
SPI6_SCK  -> PB3
SPI6_MOSI -> PB5
SPI6_MISO -> PB4
CS  -> PH0 (This is an external crystal oscillator pin but iam using it as GPIO, Will this be an issue as on this pin even if i set the GPIO to high its giving a maximum voltage of 1V)
I tried to change the CS pin instead of toggle before and after communication to ground always and used pull-up in cube ide also but nothing seems to work as i cant communicate and get proper data , chip id itself.
Here are my SPI6 configuration settings of my project, I changed the prescalar to different values but nothing is working. When I measure voltage on SPC and MOSI pins its giving 1.35V (If this would be an issue)


How to debug this issue i dont have print log iam just using Debug windows live expressions for checking change in values.
For your reference iam adding the code here like only transfer function using SPI:
int32_t spi_read_reg_mtn_snsr(void *handle, uint8_t Reg, uint8_t *pdata, uint16_t Length)

{

uint8_t ret;

Reg = Reg|0x80;

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

//HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi6) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}

ret=HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi6, &Reg, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

if(ret != HAL_OK)

printf("\r\nSPI Read Error");

while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi6) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}

ret=HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi6, pdata, Length, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

if(ret != HAL_OK)

printf("\r\nSPI Read Error");

while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi6) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}

//HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);

return HAL_OK;

}

 

int32_t spi_write_reg_mtn_snsr(void *handle, uint8_t Reg, uint8_t *pdata, uint16_t Length)

{

uint8_t ret;

Reg = Reg & 0x7F;

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

//HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi6) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}

ret=HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi6, &Reg, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

if(ret != HAL_OK)

printf("\r\nSPI Write Error");

while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi6) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}

ret=HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi6, pdata, Length, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

if(ret != HAL_OK)

printf("\r\nSPI Write Error");

while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi6) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}

//HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOF, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);

return HAL_OK;

}

void read_chip(LSM6DSOX_Object_t *pobj)

{

LSM6DSOX_ReadID(pobj, &Chip_ID); //This is part of ST driver of lsm6dsox itself

printf("\n\rChip id is %X", Chip_ID);

}

For Reading chip_id iam using this instruction in while loop but not getting any thing:
spi_read_reg_mtn_snsr(&hspi6, LSM6DSOX_WHO_AM_I , &data1 , 1);

read_chip(pObj);

Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.
I tried grounding CS pin and changing the dpeed of spi communication on cube IDE but nothing seems to work as i couldnt read the CHIP_ID itself
